# Cannot find all connected devices to my LAN

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, wifi

I am creating a UWP application, and I am trying to find all devices connected to my LAN at home. I have a pi running windows iot that is a controller and I have another application running on my computer currently but will be running on another device later. What I need to do is find what address all pi's are and allow the user to select the one they want. I have started by just finding all things connected to my local network.

```
List<string> connectedDevices = new List<string>();
        foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
        {
            if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
            {
                if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
                {
                    connectedDevices.Add(localHostName.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        ConnectedDevices = connectedDevices;
```

This code will return some ip addresses but not the one the pi is connected to. I have verified that the pi is in fact connected by pining it and also I am able to control it when entering the ip address in my application myself.

What I am trying to accomplish is taking the master device with the display and finding the slave devices on the local network so multiple slaves can be added and if an ip address of a slave has changed it will be updated so my app can still call it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You first need to look at the ARP table which contains all the devices in the subnet.  From cmd.exe >ARP -A.  Ping is an ARP request and the results is an ARP response.  Besides a PING all devices advertise their IP when turned on and approximately ever 1/2 hour.  All devices should be in the ARP table.  The advertisement is a multicast message and is not forwarded outside a subnet except when sent as a PING.  So if you are not seeing all the devices on a LAN then all the devices are not in the same subnet. Changing the mask will sometimes help, except routers don't normally forward mutlicast.

Comment: I have checked that my development machine and the iot device are on the same subnet. I can find the iot device in the ARP table. The windows iot core dashboard can find all iot devices and lists them so I assume my iot device is setup correctly and perhaps it is just something with my method?

Comment: After some looking around it would seem that uwp devices do not have access to the ARP table.

Comment: UWP aren't implementing normal IP protocols.  Windows devices are tunneling through windows operating system to make connections.  So standard ARP protocol is not being used and PING won't work.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like what I am trying to do is not possible in UWP. I will have to figure another way to get what I need.